# Hibernate 5.0 Select Join ManyToMny with @JoinColumn bug

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpql

Hi I have a question about queries with Hibernate and JPA, I hava a manytomany relationship and I use @JoinTable and specify the table name and fields, the application start normally, but when I try run a jpql with join a exception is throwed saying who don't have table with name "a_b", but in my annotation I specfy a name "c":

```
public class A {
        @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
        @JoinTable(name = "C", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_a")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_b")})
        private List<B> b = new ArrayList<B>();
}

public class B{
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<A> a = new ArrayList<A>;
}
```

If I mapping like this the exception say how not found a table with name a_b, even I specify table name in @Join table, this is a bug? How can I say to Hibernate search for table "c" ?

Comment: I see no X name in given snippet, nor mentioned Y. Most probably error is somewhere else

Comment: Sorry, I changed names when I write a example, look at only the code please, disconsider "x" and "Y" and consider "A" and "B"

Comment: No, you will edit your question to make any sense and I will retract my downvote.

Comment: It's done, sorry is my first time here

Comment: You have defined two separate, unidirectional ManyToMany associations here. And the problem is about a query throwing an excaption, but you didn't post the query, nor the exception stack trace.

Comment: I solved the problem, the solution is put @JoinTable in two sides.

I appreciate the attention and patience of friends.

Comment: @JoseLuizJunior no, that's not the solution. The solution is to read the manual to learn how to correctly map a bidirectional association. You haven't. One side needs to be the inverse side, and use mappedBy.